# Proof with Topological Definition of Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I am using the following definition of continuity: $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for each open subset $V\subset Y$, $f^{−1}(V)$ is an open subset of $X$.

Using this definition, how would I show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous? If I choose an interval $(a, b),$ I get that $f^{-1}(a, b) = (a^2, b^2),$ which is open. But how do I show that $f$ is continuous at $0$, as I cannot construct an open interval containing $0$ because negative numbers are not in the range of $f$?

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $D=[0,\infty [$. Think about the induced topology in $D$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I'm not sure I understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since open intervals form a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ it's enough to check that for all open intervals $(a,b)$, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is open in its domain.

Clearly domain of $f$ should be $X=[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is endowed with the subspace topology. Let $(a,b)$ be an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (where $a,b$ are allowed to be $-\infty,\infty$). We may assume $b>0$, since otherwise $f^{-1}(a,b)=\emptyset$ which is clearly oepn.

If $a\ge 0$ then $f^{-1}(a,b)=(a^2,b^2)$ is clearly open in $X$.

If $a<0$ then $f^{-1}(a,b)=[0,b^2)=(-\infty,b^2)\cap X$ is also open in the view of the subspace topology.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you explain what you mean by "is also open in view of the subspace topology"? Isn't it a problem that $0$ is not an interior point?

Comment: Do you know about the subspace topology? Given a topological space $X$ (here $X=\mathbb{R}$) and a subset $Y\subset X$ ($Y=[0,\infty)$), we can regard $Y$ as a topological subspace of $X$ by declaring opens sets of $Y$ are precisely the ones that has the form $U\cap Y$ where $U$ is an open set of $X$. Clearly, $(-\infty,b^2)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, and $[0,b^2)=(-\infty,b^2)\cap [0,\infty)$ so by definition this set is open in $[0,\infty)$ where we regarded $[0,\infty)$ as a topological subspcae of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a topological space $(X,\mu)$ and a subset $Y\subset X$, we define
$\sigma=\{A\cap Y: A\in\mu\}$ as the induced topology in $Y$ and we obtain a new topological space $(Y,\sigma)$ (note that the open sets in $Y$, element of $\sigma$ couldn't be open sets in $X$ -- depends if $Y$ is or not is an open in $X$).

For example, if $X=\Bbb R$ with the canonical topology and $Y=[0,1)$, the set $[0,\frac12)$ is open in $Y$ (because $[0,\frac12) = (-1,\frac12)\cap Y$ and $(-1,\frac12)$ is open in $X$).

Therefore, you have to think about where $f$ is defined.